# How to make OpenSSL use http instead of https?

Tags: c++, http, ssl, https, openssl

So what I want is simple -I love openSSL api. I found some [simple code to begin with](http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/108/OpenSSL_Server_Example.html) for learning it. I am quite new to server creation stuff. I wonder - how to make OpenSSL work with simple http instead of https? I mean I want to provide same service, be capable to jump into https when I need to but have no protection http vercion of it.

I mean It is so grate just to say

```
 SSLServer server("cert", "pkey", 1420);

  // Set the thread function.
  server.SetPthread_F(conn_thread);
```

I wish I could do same for not protected http service creation.

After some grate answers I understood I shall edit main question:

How to keep/use only non-blocking TCP server part of OpenSSL library? Main goal would be a crossplatform small and simple in use TCP server on top of which it would be eazy to implement http and http costumized analogs

So If we look onto example:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "sslserver.h"

#define REPLY "<html><body>Metalshell.com OpenSSL Server</body></html>"
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE 1024

// Called when a new connection is made.
void *conn_thread(void *ssl) {
  int fd = SSL_get_fd((SSL *)ssl);

  if(SSL_accept((SSL *)ssl) == -1) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  } else {
    char cipdesc[128];
    SSL_CIPHER *sslciph = SSL_get_current_cipher((SSL *)ssl);

    cout << "Encryption Description:\n";
    cout << SSL_CIPHER_description(sslciph, cipdesc, sizeof(cipdesc)) << endl;

    char buff[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
    // Wait for data to be sent.
    int bytes = SSL_read((SSL *)ssl, buff, sizeof(buff));
    buff[bytes] = '\0';

    // Show the browser request.
    cout << "Recieved: \n" << buff << endl;

    // Send the html reply.
    SSL_write((SSL *)ssl, REPLY, strlen(REPLY));
  }

  // Tell the client we are closing the connection.
  SSL_shutdown((SSL *)ssl);

  // We do not wait for a reply, just clear everything.
  SSL_free((SSL *)ssl);
  close(fd);

  cout << "Connection Closed\n";
  cout << "---------------------------------------------\n";

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
  SSLServer server("cert", "pkey", 1420);

  // Set the thread function.
  server.SetPthread_F(conn_thread);

  while(1) {
    /* Wait for 10 seconds, and if no one trys
     * to connect return back.  This allows us to do
     * other things while waiting.
     */
    server.CheckClients(10);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What shall be changed to our server accept all connections  not only ssl ones (cout full request if possible) and send them REPLYs?

Comment: This sounds like a question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HTTPS **is** simple HTTP with SSL (the implementations of which is the point of OpenSSL). The S in HTTPS stands for secure.

Don't use the OpenSSL API when you don't want SSL.

Comment: generally what I loved about openSSL is service creation api - Is there any alike lib for simple http services or any way to set protection to nan with openssl when needed?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [OpenSSL Book](http://www.opensslbook.com) in chapter 5 (I think), they build a simple SSL server in a series of steps.  The first step uses the OpenSSL API to do plaintext (non-SSL) network I/O, which is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've referenced is a trivial implementation of non-blocking TCP server + SSL. So what you need to do is strip OpenSSL from that code and you have a trivial implementation of nonblocking TCP server. Note, that this is very far from real HTTP server - it performs no request parsing at all (which can be non-trivial) and responds with a predefined response. So if you need an HTTP / HTTPS *server*, you need to search for corresponding third-party library or code.

Comment: It would be more than enough for me to have simple TCP server on top of crossplatform tcp socket wrapper so the question evoles in to how to strip TCP server functionalyty out of that sample code.

Comment: @Kabumbus doing google search for "simple http server C++ code" reveals a couple of [re]usable servers which will give you what you need without a hassle of stripping openssl from the sample that you used.

Comment: point here is to do it wit openssl for capabilety of future fast jump into https world=)

Comment: @Kabumbus I don't see that OpenSSL supports passthrough mode (which would let you to just turn SSL on and off). Try checking one of other HTTP server code samples, maybe they provide more flexibility regarding SSL

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS will work only when both the client and server side applications are "AWARE" of the transaction will happen in SSL. Most applications therefore have independent entry points for ssl and non-ssl communication, for example HTTP is usually on port 80 while HTTPS would be port 443. If the client starts transaction on the port 80, and if the server-side application determines that rest of the exchange must be secured, it "redirects" the client application to transact on port 443. For example if you access http://www.gmail.com the transaction begins with communication on port 80, however since this application requires you to login securely, it redirects your browser to open a new connection to another url on port 443.

You too can do the same, and yes while the transactions are happening in the SSL you can direct the client to start transacting on port unsecured port 80 too.